# Laravel 5.7 verification email has wrong url when sending email through event

Tags: laravel, email, laravel-5.7

I'm trying to use laravel's 5.7 email verification to send an email when an account is registered. I have an event that fires that send the url when a user is registered. The event dispatch can be seen here.

```
 protected function registered(Request $request, $user)
{
    UserRegistered::dispatch($user);
}
```

The event fires and a listener sends an email by using the following code.

```
public function handle(UserRegistered $event)
{
    $event->user->notify(new VerifyEmail);
}
```

This then does send the email verification mail to my email address so the event is working. However the issue I'm having is the verification email link that is contained in the email is incorrect.

```
 http://localhost/email/verify/19?expires=1544182945&signature=b4337e1c7e07a7e7117a8696a30b456ab2a304cdea563ca7aea6c90bb9a2541f
```

Here is what is being sent by email. However the app url should not be localhost and instead by core-site.test. e.g. http://core-site.test/email/verify etc...

Does anyone know why the url is incorrect and how I can fix it?

Comment: Did you define the `APP_URL` in your .env?

Comment: Yep it looks like this APP_URL=http://core-site.test

Comment: Is your config cached? Try `php artisan config:clear`

Comment: Tried it but the email link is still localhost

Comment: @JamieWoods check in `VerifyEmail` code how the url is set, hard coded?

Comment: The url is generated using a method called verificationUrl.

Comment: The code looks like this    return URL::temporarySignedRoute(
            'verification.verify', Carbon::now()->addMinutes(60), ['id' => $notifiable->getKey()]
        );

Comment: @JamieWoods r u using queue? If so can u restart the queue & check

Comment: I don't use a queue for the event listener that dispatches the email.

Comment: @JamieWoods It should use the `APP_URL` in your `.env` file. Double check `config/app.php` url using that env variable.

Comment: app.php is set as followed     'url' => 'http://core-site.test',

Comment: Any update on this? I'm facing the same issue on one specific server

Comment: Same problem,cant find any clue...any update please post it here